# Infinite value in covariance in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, minimize

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

y = np.array([25.885,26.139,27.404,30.230]) 
y_err = np.array([1.851,0.979,2.049,6.729]) 
x = np.array([0,1,2,3]) 

def func(X, a, b):
    x,y,weight=X
    return (a * (x+0.5)/4.186 + b-y)**2/weight

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x,y,y_err), 0)
print(popt)
print(pcov)
```

It's just a simple fitting routing y vs x, but I rewrite it in such a way as to be able to try different definitions for the loss on the fit, so I basically want to minimize the function I have and hence the output should be as close as possible to zero. I later realized there is a minimize function in python, but leaving that aside, I get this covariance matrix:

```
[[inf inf]
 [inf inf]]
```

while the actual parameters for a and b look quite resonable: `[5.23,24.68]`

What is going on? Thank you!

Comment: For the parameter `X`, where `x,y,weight=X` in the function `func`, you assign `x` which is `x = np.array([0,1,2,3])`. Does it make sense? Regarding the result `ìnf`, the function is not minimizing at the moment, apparently.

Comment: @Iammuratc If by making sense you mean if that is what I want, then yes, that is what I want the independent variable to be. I updated my answer. The values for a and b get changed and they look okish (the values are not crazy). It's just the covariance matrix that is not working. Also it's a linear fit, so I don't understand why it would have issues finding a minima.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Your code runs without having infs in the covariance matrix for me. I also get the correct results for parameters a and b.

Comment: @Tinu what python version do you use? Also what values do you get for a, b and the covariance parameters?

Comment: python 3.8.2, numpy 1.18.3, scipy 1.4.1, pcov=[[ 0.95693377, -0.34444467],[-0.34444467,  0.16432083]] and a = 5.22891653, b = 24.68348444

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.6. That might be the problem?

Comment: The python version most likely not, maybe the version of scipy you use. If you tell me your scipy and numpy versions (print(np.__verions__) & print(scipy.__verion__)) I could create an environment and try to reproduce your result.